# Google Analytics grouping by screen width

Tags: google-analytics

I have ton of results with screen size something like:

```
933x621
934x650
930x600

420x350
422x515
425x610
```

etc... All of them have some visits.

Is it posible, and how, to group all this results in to something like

```
900-950x(any height)
400-450x(any height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a segment based on the resolution and regex the hell out of it.

Here is a segment for 400-450x(any height) https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=6YuJbBJzQA2uOuBXuqvWjA

it's based on the regex `^4[0-5][0-9]x.*` for the `Screen Resolution` dimension

for more info about numeric ranges in RegEx have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html